How can one update/create ConfigMap with kube-rs
I am looking for a simple example to add a value to an existing ConfigMap with kube-rs.
I have seen the configmapgen_controller.rs example, but I am not sure what part is needed for a minimal example (e.g., do I need the generator?)
So what I naively tried (also Rust Newbie, so apologize for basic mistakes and appreciate feedback):
    let  cm_patch = ConfigMap {
        binary_data: cm1.binary_data,
        data: Some(map),
        immutable: cm1.immutable,
        metadata: cm1.metadata
    };

    /// Update
    cm_api
        .patch(
            Option::from(config_map_name).ok_or_else(|| Error::MissingObjectKey(".metadata.name"))?,
            &PatchParams::apply("configmapgenerator.kube-rt.nullable.se"),
            &Patch::Apply(&cm_patch),
        )
        .await
        .map_err(Error::ConfigMapCreationFailed)?;

It does not feel right to recreate the entire ConfigMap and secondly struggling with the following API error: Error: ConfigMapCreationFailed(Api(ErrorResponse { status: "Failure", message: "metadata.managedFields must be nil", reason: "BadRequest", code: 400 }))
Any pointers are welcome!

Please create a Minimal Reproducible Example, i.e. a snippet we can run ourselves, or at least specify all types used in their full path.
